# Angular Custom Form Control never make my Form dirty

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created a custom form control but whenever the value changes, it does not mark the form dirty. I don't understand what should be done.

This is the code of my custom component :

```typescript
    import { ThrowStmt } from '@angular/compiler';
    import { Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
    import { ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
    import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-multiple-checkbox',
      templateUrl: './multiple-checkbox.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./multiple-checkbox.component.scss'],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => MultipleCheckboxComponent),
          multi: true
        },
        {
          provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: forwardRef(() => MultipleCheckboxComponent),
          multi: true
        }]
    })
    export class MultipleCheckboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    
      value = [];
      disabled = false;
    
      @Input() public options: { key, value }[];
      @Output() haschanged = new EventEmitter();
    
      onChange: any = (key) => {
        this.haschanged.emit(key, this.value);
      }
    
      onTouched: any = () => { };
    
      constructor() { }
    
      validate({ value }: FormControl) {
        const isNotValid = this.value.length === 0;
        return isNotValid && {
          invalid: true
        };
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
      evaluate(event, key): void {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          this.value.push(key);
        } else {
          this.value.splice(this.value.findIndex(i => key === i), 1);
        }
    
        this.onTouched(this.value);
        this.onChange(key, this.value);
      }
    
      isChecked(key): boolean {
        return this.value.findIndex(e => e === key) > -1;
      }
    
      writeValue(value: any): void {
        this.value = value;
      }
      registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
      }
      registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
      }
      setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
      }
    
    }
```

The view is the following one :

```html
    <div *ngFor="let option of options">
        <label [attr.for]="option.key">{{option.value}}</label>
        <input [id]="option.key" type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked(option.key)" [disabled]="disabled" (change)="evaluate($event, option.key)">
    </div>
```

What is missing to make the form dirty  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that are not quite right in your implementation.

1. `onChange` function will be assigned a value in the line `onChange = fn` so the below code will not be be used

```typescript
  onChange: any = (key) => {
    this.haschanged.emit(key, this.value);
  }
```

So change this to `onChange: any;`

2. The below line reassigns our `onChange` function, an unexpected results is bound to occur here

```typescript
registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.onChange = fn;
}
```

Change the above to

```typescript
onTouched: any;
registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.onTouched = fn;
}
```

3. Remove `EventEmitter`. You probably was trying to emit events but when using `ControlValueAccessor` angular should do the rest for you including event emissions. Also **very important** `EventEmitter` is imported from `@angular/core` and not from `events`
4. Change your evaluate function to call the `onTouched` and `onChange` functions like below

```typescript
  evaluate(event, key): void {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.value.push(key);
    } else {
      this.value.splice(this.value.findIndex(i => key === i), 1);
    }
    this.onChange(this.value);
    this.onTouched();
  }
```

With these changes, Angular will do the rest for you including setting a form to dirty, touched and valid states

[See this demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pakpnv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmulticheckbox%2Fmulticheckbox.component.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Owen, this is a great reply and you solved my problem. It is the first time I try to create a custom form control and although I went through the documentation, things were still a bit confused for me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just one side-question if you don't mind. You have mentioned I don't need the event emitter. But in my parent form, to which event should I subscribe to in order to take action whenever a form control was changed ?

Comment: You can use the control like a normal input, the custom-control will emit the `change` event like any other input so you can do something like `(change)="onChangeEvent($event)"`

Comment: Or simply subscribe to the valueChanges property of the formGroup e.g in my stackblitz demo I have updated the code with `this.myForm.get('games').valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)`

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not express myself correctly. I wanted to do `this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe() `  so that I take the same action whatever the change is. But in the subscribe I'd like to know which control has triggered the event and could not find a way to do that (this is why I started using the EventEmitter)

Comment: I see, I think for that you may need to the event emitter, just remember `import EventEmitter from '@angular/core'`

Answer (score 0):

based on the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) it says

> On blur (or equivalent), your class should call the registered
> function to allow the forms API to update itself:

```
host: {
   '(blur)': '_onTouched()'
}
```

same thing occurs for change event, plus you are missing the aim of `ControlValueAccessor` it is meant to be used with `ngModel` or with ReactiveForms with `FormControls`
Here is the directive used under the hood for checkboxes in forms

[source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.ts)

so you can see how is implemented a class that implements `ControlValueAccessor`that may be a good start